# where does java look for files in netbeans? And is it possible to change the directory?

Tags: java, maven, netbeans

So, I've got some txt files that I want to place in the following folder: `src/test/resources/__files`

However, when I run my project, I find that the compiler is looking for files in the project folder. Is there anyway of changing this as it becomes problematic when I try to create a JAR file - those files are then needed to be manually added to the target folder.

Thanks

Comment: Is your project a Maven or Gradle project?  Those frameworks have places where you may put your resource files such that they would end up on your classpath.

Comment: its a maven project

Answer (score 3):

Since you are already placing your resource files in the `src/test/resources` folder, Maven should make them available on the classpath at runtime.  In this case, they should be on the classpath in your test build.  You may try the following code:

```
String fileName = "somefile.txt";
ClassLoader classLoader = getClass().getClassLoader();
File file = new File(classLoader.getResource(fileName).getFile());
```

The [Mkyong site](https://www.mkyong.com/java/java-read-a-file-from-resources-folder/) does a good job of explaining how resources work in Maven.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be working with the **maven** build tool, with per convention src/main/java, src/main/resources and for unit tests src/test/java and src/test/resources.

And then the files are not real file system File, but resources, packaged possibly in a jar (as you said): case-sensitive, `/` path separator and read-only InputStream.

You could keep the file as resource (under /src/main/resources/ then), and use that file as template for a real File, at the application `System.getProperty("user.dir")` (working directory), or `System.getProperty("user.home")` (home directory), see [System Properties](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/sysprop.html).

```
InputStream in = .... .class.getResourceAsStream("___files/xyz.txt");
```

Or you could in maven copy from your own location to the target/distribution directory.

Answer (score 0):

I use NetBeans on Windows I write `String url = "src\\test\\resources\\__files"`
Folder structure
`ProjFolder\src\test\resources\__files`